# How can I disable welcome Rundeck page right after login to rundeck?

Tags: rundeck

I am looking for an option that can disable the welcome rundeck page after logging into rundeck.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project the default page is "projectHome". A simple way to avoid this web is to create a new project.

But also, you can set a default page after login with: `rundeck.gui.startpage` parameter at rundeck-config.properties and restart the service.

You have more information here: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/gui-customization.html (rundeck.gui.startpage section).

Comment: Thanks, 
rundeck.gui.startpage this option shows the page after selecting the project in rundeck.
I am looking for an option where right after starting the rundeck at a very first time, welcome page should not be shown up.